# pl/sql query to find out the manager name by deptno

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

pl/sql query to find out the manager name by deptno

```
DECLARE
V_ENAME EMP.ENAME%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
FOR I IN (SELECT distinct  DEPTNO FROM EMP) 
LOOP 
SELECT ENAME INTO V_ENAME FROM EMP 
 WHERE JOB='MANAGER' AND DEPTNO=I.DEPTNO; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NAME OF THE MANAGER IN '||I.DEPTNO||' IS '||V_ENAME);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is no such thing as PL/SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine

```
DECLARE
V_ENAME EMP.ENAME%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
FOR I IN (SELECT distinct  DEPTNO FROM EMP) 
LOOP 
SELECT ENAME INTO V_ENAME FROM EMP 
WHERE JOB='MANAGER' AND DEPTNO=I.DEPTNO; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NAME OF THE MANAGER IN DEPARTMENT '||I.DEPTNO||' IS '||V_ENAME);
END LOOP;
END;
```

prints

`THE NAME OF THE MANAGER IN DEPARTMENT 30 IS BLAKE
 THE NAME OF THE MANAGER IN DEPARTMENT 20 IS JONES
 THE NAME OF THE MANAGER IN DEPARTMENT 10 IS CLARK`

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no idea what is the point of this thread I will provide simple SQL query that does what was was asked in the question - gets deptno of the department and name of the manager (using scalar subquery).

```
select d.deptno,
       (select e.ename
          from emp e
         where e.deptno = d.deptno
           and e.job = 'MANAGER') manager
  from dept d;
```

There is no reason to use PL/SQL here.